# fpsync syntax error

Tags: centos, rsync, synchronization, oracle-linux, data

```
[oraadmin@sgwmsdbsprd03 ~]$ fpsync -v -n 8 -o "-lptgoD -v --numeric-ids -e ssh -p 222" /app/test/ oraadmin@10.150.3.90:/app/testing
1661915613 Info: Run ID: 1661915613-41320
1661915613 ===> Analyzing filesystem...
1661915614 <=== Fpart crawling finished
1661915615 <=== Parts done: 1/1 (100%), remaining: 0
1661915615 <=== Time elapsed: 2s, remaining: ~0s (~2s/job)
1661915615 <=== Fpsync completed with errors in 2s, see logs:
/tmp/fpsync/log/1661915613-41320/1.stderr
```

This is output of `/tmp/fpsync/log/1661915613-41320/1.stderr`

```
Use "rsync --daemon --help" to see the daemon-mode command-line options.
Please see the rsync(1) and rsyncd.conf(5) man pages for full documentation.
See http://rsync.samba.org/ for updates, bug reports, and answers
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(2354) [client=3.1.3]
```

What's wrong with my command?

Comment: You should read the file `/tmp/fpsync/log/1661915613-41320/1.stderr`. If you cannot understand the contents, please **edit your question** to add the contents of that file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `-lptgoD -v` from the options list as this is already included in the default `rsync -av` command generated by `fpsync`.
2. You haven't quoted the parameters for the `-e ssh -p 222` so these will be passed directly to `rsync` as four separate words instead of just two. Either set up an ssh configuration entry in `~/.ssh/config` to use port 222 automatically for the target host, or try single-quoting the string: `-e 'ssh -p 222' ...` inside the already double-quoted list of `rsync` options.